# Sphinx doesn't search via php api but does via console

Tags: php, sphinx

When I search via console sphinx works fine:

```
index 'dreamsIndex': query 'demo': returned 2 matches of 2 total in 0.017 sec

displaying matches:
1. document=494, weight=1620
2. document=495, weight=1620

words:
1. 'd500': 2 documents, 2 hits
```

But when I do the same search via php api, I get no results. In fact, `$result['total_found']` has the correct value 2, but `$result['matches']` is empty.

```
   include_once('sphinxapi.php');
   $sphinx = new SphinxClient();
   $sphinx->SetServer("localhost", 9312);
   $sphinx->SetConnectTimeout(1);
   $sphinx->SetArrayResult(true);
   $sphinx->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
   $sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE)
   $result = $sphinx->Query("demo","*");
   if ($result===false) echo "Error: ".$sphinx->GetLastError();
   else {
       if ($sphinx->GetLastWarning()) echo "Warning: ".$sphinx->GetLastWarning();
            echo "Total found: ".$result['total_found']."\r\n";                                      
            if (sizeof($result['matches'])) {                          
                      foreach ($result['matches'] as $val) {
                       echo "id = ".$val['attrs']['id']."\r\n";
                     }
            }
  }
```

Actually `$result['matches']` doesn't even exist. There is `$result['attrs']`, but it's empty.

[**Here is how `$result` looks like (link)**](http://pastebin.com/ZacDTFqV)

I'm confused.

Comment: Can you include a print_r of the whole $result structure? Maybe use pastebin.com rather than add it all here.

Comment: Solved it. The problem was in incorrect $sphinx->SetLimits which I didn't post here (should've posted).